# How to deserialize Json API response in Java? And how to use it response to call another API?

Tags: java, c#, json, api

Hi one year ago I've created a code in C# that I used to deserialize an Json API using RestClient.
Now I want to do it in Java to integrate that with Jenkins. **Basically I want to use an API response body to get it data and automatically call another API**.

Here is the code that I've created in c#

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using App4.Resources;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace App4
{
    [Activity(Label = "Whirlpool Consulta de API", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        EditText edtcpf;
        Button btnConsumer;
        TextView txtcpf;
        RestRequest cpf { get; set; }
        public RestClient consumer { get; set; }
        IRestResponse mensagemConsumer;
        RestClient orderId { get; set; }
        RestRequest requestorderId { get; set; }
        IRestResponse answerorder { get; set; }
        TextView txtnome;
        public List<string> lista;
        ListView mlistview;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        // ImageView imageView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            txtcpf = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtcpf);
            mlistview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView2);
            txtnome = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNome);
            edtcpf = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtcpf);
            btnConsumer = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConsumer);
            //imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
            btnConsumer.Click += BtnConsumer_Click;
            lista = new List<string>();
        }

        private void BtnConsumer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // API Consumer CPF
            /* ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
             progress.Indeterminate = true;
             progress.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
             progress.SetMessage("Carregando. Por favor aguarde...");
             //progress.SetCancelable(false);
             progress.Show();*/

            try
            {
                var limpa = "";

                showbox("Iniciando Pesquisa...");

                consumer = new RestClient("https://qa.api-latam.whirlpool.com/v1.0/consumers");
                cpf = new RestRequest("/" + edtcpf.Text, Method.GET);
                cpf.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                cpf.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer fed6b2f0-7aba-3339-9813-7fc9387e2581");
                mensagemConsumer = consumer.Execute(cpf);
                Pessoa pessoa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pessoa>(mensagemConsumer.Content);
                txtnome.Text = "Nome: " + pessoa.firstName + " " + pessoa.lastName
```

This is the code that I want to convert to Java. Is it hard? And how to use an API response to call another API? For example: get the user ID and send it as a parameter in another API.

Regards,
Lucas